# Why doesn't this for loop in Python take ages?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, ipython

I am running this little loop on a Jupyter notebook

```
import time

def time_loop(reps):

    start = time.clock()
    count = 0
    for i in range(reps):
        count += 1
    return time.clock() - start

time_loop(10000^100)
```

No matter what I enter as an argument, I seem to always get an output around 0.003

```
0.0031050000000050204
```

What is going on?

One guess is that python understands that the result of the loop will simply be count = reps, and quits the loop?

But if I run this instead

```
import time
import numpy as np

def time_loop(reps):

    start = time.clock()
    count = 0
    for i in range(reps):
        count += np.sin(reps)
    return time.clock() - start

time_loop(10000^100)
```

It does take longer as I increase the argument, even though the result of the loop is still quite simply count = reps*sin(reps).

Comment: What do you think `10000^100` computes?  It's not exponentiation - it's exclusive `or`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` is xor and not exponentation:

```
>>> 10000^100
10100
```

That's a big number but not like with exponentation: `**`, that returns:

```
>>> 10000**100
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

That also takes a "while" to iterate over.

A good reference for the operators and their precedence is avaiable in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence):

> ^     - Bitwise XOR
>
> **    - Exponentiation